# Explain the stored procedure described below

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_plan_images`(
    _list varchar(2000)
)
BEGIN
   SET @LIST=_list;
   set @sql = concat('SELECT plan_id, plan_image 
                        FROM ibuild.plan_images 
                       where plan_id in (', @LIST , ')');
   PREPARE q FROM @sql;
   execute q;
END
```

What does `concat` do here? And what does this statement means `PREPARE q FROM @sql;`

Comment: [mysql concat function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [mysql prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) Always look for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT simply merges two or more pieces of text together. In the example above, @LIST contains a list of ids passed in to the procedure. After the CONCAT, @sql becomes a string that contains something like:`SELECT plan_id, plan_image FROM ibuild.plan_images where plan_id in (1,2,3)`

See here: [MySQL CONCAT Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp)

The PREPARE statement just gives the statement a name so you can execute it. See here: [MySQL PREPARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html)